# How to iterate through all parent nodes of treeview control in c++?

Tags: c++, mfc, treeview

I am new to C++. Is there any way to iterate through all parent nodes starting from the tree ?

Ex :

```
ParentNode1->Child1
           ->Child2

ParentNode2->Child1
           ->Child2
```

I want to iterate from ParentNode1 to ParentNode2.

Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following functions to traverse the MFC `CTreeCtrl`:

```
void TraverseTree(CTreeCtrl* pTreeCtrl)
{
    TraverseTreeBranch(pTreeCtrl, pTreeCtrl->GetRootItem(), TVI_ROOT);
}

void TraverseTreeBranch(CTreeCtrl* pTreeCtrl, HTREEITEM hItem, HTREEITEM hParentItem)
{
    // Do stuff with hItem here

    HTREEITEM hItemTmp = pTreeCtrl->GetChildItem(hItem);
    while(hItemTmp != NULL)
    {
        TraverseTreeBranch(pTreeCtrl, hItemTmp, hNewItem);
        hItemTmp = GetNextSiblingItem(hItemTmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in this answer does not address the question. As implemented, it visits **all** nodes. Since it implements depth-first iteration (vs. breadth-first), iteration of nodes on the same level is intermingled with recursion calls, and harder to follow than necessary. If you strip out all the unrelated code and show a simple `TraverseSiblings` function only, it'll make for a far better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [CTreeView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th0y74x7.aspx) class wraps a [CTreeCtrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bkz91b4.aspx) object. The latter provides [CTreeCtrl::GetNextSiblingItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfh3f9zt.aspx)/[CTreeCtrl::GetPrevSiblingItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1232x235.aspx). Those members return the next/previous treeview item, that's on the same hierarchy level.

---

If you are looking for a Windows API solution, use the [TreeView_GetNextSibling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773867.aspx)/[TreeView_GetPrevSibling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773875.aspx) macros instead, or send a [TVM_GETNEXTITEM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773622.aspx) message.